# Reactjs: The value of the input element, required for a controlled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In my project, there is an input field to add email tags. Now it shows an error

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

interface details{
    item: string
}

// type Props = {
//     test: string,
//     // error: string,
//   };
  

export const TagActions = () => {
    // var { test } = props
    const [items, setItem] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    const [error, setError]= useState('')

    const handleDelete = (item:any) => {
        const result = items.filter(i => i !== item)
        setItem(result)
      };
    
    const handleItemEdit = (item:any) =>{
        const result = items.filter(i => i !== item)
        setItem(result)
        setValue(value)
        
    };

    const handleKeyDown = (evt:any) => {
        if (["Enter", "Tab", ","].includes(evt.key)) {
          evt.preventDefault();

          var test = value.trim();
    
          if (test && isValid(test)) {
            items.push(test)
            setValue("")
           
          }
        }
    };

    const isValid = (email:any)=> {
        let error = null;
    
        if (isInList(email)) {
          error = `${email} has already been added.`;
        }
    
        if (!isEmail(email)) {
          error = `${email} is not a valid email address.`;
        }
    
        if (error) {
            setError(error);
    
          return false;
        }
    
        return true;
    }

    const isInList = (email:any)=> {
        return items.includes(email);
      }
    
    const isEmail = (email:any)=> {
        return /[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[\w\d\.-]+/.test(email);
    }

    const handleChange = (evt:any) => {
        setValue(evt.target.value)
        // setError("")
        
    };

    const handlePaste = (evt:any) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
    
        var paste = evt.clipboardData.getData("text");
        var emails = paste.match(/[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[\w\d\.-]+/g);
    
        if (emails) {
          var toBeAdded = emails.filter((email:any) => !isInList(email));
            
            setItem(toBeAdded)
        
        }
    };
    


    return (
        <>
          
          <TextField id="outlined-basic" variant="outlined"
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: items.map(item => (
              <Chip
                key={item}
                tabIndex={-1}
                label={item}
                onDelete={() => handleDelete(item)}
                onClick={() => handleItemEdit(item)}
              />
            )),
  
          }}
            ref={items}
            value={value}
            placeholder="Type or paste email addresses and press `Enter`..."
            onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange}
            onPaste={() => handlePaste}
          />
  
          {error && <p className="error">{error}</p>}
        </>
      );
}
```

I already tried some solutions But the expected result did not come. I don't know if there are other ways to do such functions because I am a beginner in react typescript. so I don't know how to fix this. Please give me some valuable suggestions to fix this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You are passing `items` as `ref`, but you can only pass variable returned by `useRef` there. For example:

```
const [string, setString] = useState<string>("")
const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

return <div ref={string}>text</div> // not ok
return <div ref={divRef}>text</div> // ok
```

Comment: Its not working, there is an another error "TS2322: Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | undefined>' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
      Type 'HTMLDivElement | undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'."

Comment: Try doing `const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)`. That's the way element refs need to be initialized in TS. Since they default to `null` instead of the usual `undefined`. Should fix your issue. @user15361826